# image doesn't render when using next.js Image tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, next.js

I have an image located in the *public/img* directory. I want to render it using the next.js built-in `<Image/>` tag.

here is the code I have written:

```js
     <Image
                onClick={hideModal}
                alt="close_button"
                src="/img/close_button.png"
                width="20px"
                height="20px"
              />
```

but nothing is shown on the page (not even the alt-text).

the thing is when I use the `<img/>` tag, it works as expected but with the `<Image/>`, it doesn't

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you please provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

doest need add img folder just add /close-button.png